# Python ncurses program stops working when resizing command prompt to mininimum size

Tags: python, windows, ncurses, python-curses, pdcurses

I'm currently facing a problem where my program seems to work fine when the windows cmd has a height of at least 3 rows. However when the cmd is resized smaller than that, ncurses stops updating the cmd dimensions (self.x, self.y) which breaks my program even when the cmd is resized to a 'normal' size afterwards.

If been having quite a bit of resizing problems with ncurses in Python besides this one. Is this a known problem or am I missing something here?

```
    def run(self):
        self.update_screen()

        while True:
            c = self.stdscr.getch()
            
            if c == ord('q'):
                break
            elif c == curses.KEY_RESIZE:
                try:
                    self.resize()
                    self.update_screen()
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)

    def resize(self):
        self.y, self.x = self.stdscr.getmaxyx()
        ... # Windows that will get resized based on the new y and x.
```

I can't seem to find an answer on google that fixes this problem.

Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/F7aYnMBP

Comment: What does `self.sb_dim.update()` do? Are you sure it's ok with a negative argument?

Comment: sb_dim stands for side_bar_dimensions, a window I created, my class update() func recalculates the new width, height etc. of the side_bar window. I don't think it should change anything so I removed it from the question.

Comment: Did you verify that it doesn't change anything? Please be aware that since you didn't provide a [mre], no-one can attempt to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I just checked and it doesn't change anything. I added a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/F7aYnMBP

Comment: The example doesn't show anything that's telling ncurses to resize its windows (the use of `resize` in the example is misleading).

Comment: I tried your code on an Ubuntu system, and it worked fine. Only then did I notice that you were working with Windows, in which case you are in all probability using the PDCurses curses implementation, not ncurses. I added some tags, although I didn't delete ncurses. Perhaps I should have.